# Adding product with size to shopping bag django

Tags: django

I am developing my hobby ecommerce store website. The products in the store can have different sizes. Wehen we go to product details page I am able to render the product's available sizes. I have also built shopping bag page and can add products to the shopping cart. Product detail page shows product color, product size and quantity. I am rendering the size in a button at the moment. When I click on Add to Bag button I want a function that checks if any size is selected, if not then raise an error message for user but if any size is selected by user then this should be sent to the view so it can be handled accordingly.

Here are my models, product detail template and product detail view: if anyone please guide me....

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Product model to allow creating product records and linking with category 
    """
    product_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    product_description = models.TextField()
    has_sizes = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product_sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'

class ProductVariation(models.Model):
    """
    ProductVariation model to allow creating product with different size and color
    """
    product_var_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_variations')
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_size_variations", blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey('Color', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_color_variantions")
    quantity = models .IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['product', 'color', 'size'],
                name='unique_prod_color_size_combo'
            )
        ]
        verbose_name = 'Product Variation'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Variations'


class Size(models.Model):
    product_size_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    product_size = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_size

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product Size'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Sizes'

class Color(models.Model):
    product_color_uuid = models.UUIDField(
        default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    product_color = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_color

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product Color'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Colors'


{% extends 'base.html' %}
 {% load static %} 
{% block extra_title %}Product Details{% endblock %}

{% block custom_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'products/css/products.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="product-detail-container">

        <div class="product-image">
            <img src="{% static product.product_images.first.product_image.url %}" >
        </div>
        <div class="product-detail-content">
            <p class="font-bold">
                {{product.product_name}}
            </p>
            <p class="my-3">
                £{{product.product_price}}
            </p>
            <p class="font-bold my-3">Product Detail -</p>
            <p>
                {{product.product_description}}
            </p>
            {% if color %}
            <p class="font-bold my-3">Color -</p>           
            <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 max-w-72">
                <p class="border-2 border-black text-center px-3">{{color}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if sizes != None %}
            <p class="font-bold my-3">Size -</p>
            <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
                {% for size_qty in product_variations %}
                    {% if size_qty.quantity == 0 %}
                        <button disabled class="border-2 border-black text-center px-3 line-through cursor-not-allowed uppercase">{{size_qty.size}}</button>
                    {% else %}
                        <button class="border-2 border-black text-center px-3 uppercase">{{size_qty.size}}</button>
                    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <form class="mt-5" action="{%  url 'add_to_bag' product.product_uuid %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    <span class="icon">
                        <i onclick="handleClick()" value="down" class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    </span>
                
                    <input id="quantity" readonly type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="5" data-item_id="{{product.product_uuid}}" id="id_qty_{{product.product_uuid}}" />
         
                    <span class="icon">
                        <i  onclick="handleClick()" value="up" class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                    <button class="border-2 border-black mt-3 py-1 px-5 bg-black text-white">
                        Add to Cart
                    </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="{{request.path}}">
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}

{% block postloadjs %} 
<script type="text/javascript">
    let quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value
   const handleClick = () => {
    if (event.target.getAttribute('value') === 'down' && quantity > 1) {
            quantity --
            document.getElementById('quantity').value = quantity
    }
    if (event.target.getAttribute('value') === 'up' && quantity < 5) {
            quantity ++
            document.getElementById('quantity').value = quantity
    }
   }
</script>
{% endblock %}

def product_details(request, **kwargs):
    """A view to show product details"""
    uuid = kwargs.get("product_uuid", None)

    # Get product, if not display error message and redirect to home page
    product = temp_product.get_product(product_uuid=uuid)
    if not product:
         messages.error(request, 'Product not found')
         return redirect(reverse('home'))
   
    # Get distinct color queryset belongs to a product
    color_queryset = Color.objects.filter(product_color_variantions__product=product).distinct()
    
    # Set color to None if a product does not have a color variation
    if len(color_queryset):
       color = color_queryset[0]
       color = color.product_color.capitalize()
    else:
        color = None

    # Get size queryset belongs to a product
    size_queryset = Size.objects.filter(product_size_variations__product=product)
    
    # Set sizes to None if a product does not have a size variation
    if len(size_queryset):
       size_list = []
       for size in size_queryset:
            size_list.append(size.product_size.capitalize())
       sizes =size_list     
    else:
        sizes = None
    
    # Get product variations
    product_variations = product.product_variations.all()

    template_name = "products/product_details.html"
    
    context = {
        "product": product,
        "sizes": sizes,
        "color": color,
        'product_variations': product_variations
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```